# Importing iCalendar file and display the informations of it on screen c# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icalendar, ical.net

I was trying to code a time schedule app using c# and wpf (.NET). I've searched for informations and tutorials on how to do it, but didn't find any. Also, I've tried to use the iCal.net library but I can't find the docs.
So yeah, I want to import a pre-downloaded calendar (in iCalendar format) and display it on screen, like a google calendar.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Wecome to stack, please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour  and https://stackoverflow.com/help This is not an appropriate stack question.  eg: A quick answer to display a google calendar on screen is to embed it https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en, however I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.